# Is it a bad idea to generate a lot of failed requests to firebase/google cloud storage?

Tags: firebase, hash, google-cloud-storage

I'm thinking of using firebase cloud storage for caching files that contain transpiled-code. To easily retreive the file, I'm thinking of naming it with part of the Hash of the original file that contains the untranspiled code.

Example:

> original-file.JSON // file that contains the untranspiled code
>
> 23fcc1f5.JSON // file that contains the transpiled code, named based on the hash of original-file.JSON

When the client needs the transpiled-code, the client app will request the file on the cloud storage. If the file is not available, the client app generates it and uploads it.

My concern is that, by design, there will be a lot a failed requests. Is it an issue to generate a lot of failed requests? Will cloud storage just charge me the failed requests like downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pricing for Cloud Storage is quite well documented on its [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Since no bandwidth is transferred, you won't pay a change for that for failed calls - and that is usually where the majority of the cost for Cloud Storage comes from. But, as far as I can tell, you *do* pay for failed request [operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing).

Comment: I see that cloud storage charges storage.*.get with Class B Operations pricings, so that's equivalent to 1 file read. That's fine for me, I just hope that making a lot a failed requests is not considered as an antipattern by cloud storage and that I won't get throttled for that.